# Inequality with prime numbers: $p_k+p_l+1\leq p_{k+l+1}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime. Is it true that $p_k+p_l+1\le p_{k+l+1}$ for all $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Slightly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530722

Comment: Is it true for small $k,l?$

Comment: tong_nor, you need both upper and lower bounds if there is any hope of doing this. Well-known upper bounds are available for $k \geq 6,$ with an improvement for $k \geq 20.$ So, again, it is up to you to find out whether this thing you made up is true for small numbers. Probably involves computer, but mostly effort on your part.

Comment: It is true for small $k,l$, I don't know any but $k=l=1$ example for equality.

Comment: Perhaps use $n\ln n+n\ln\ln n-n<p_n<n\ln n+n\ln\ln n$, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#cite_ref-27).

Comment: It's too weak (I checked and made a graph of the difference as a function of $l$ for some fixed $k$)

Comment: Any thoughts/questions about my answer?

Comment: Earth to tong_nor: Come in, please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my question is hard and undecidable because it is almost equivalent to an open number-theory problem?

Comment: "Undecidable" is a technical term coming from math logic, so I didn't and wouldn't use it. But, yes, your question is more-or-less equivalent to a notorious open problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with higher mathematics, and my english is not perfect, so sorry for unfortunate words.
I meant "undecidable with current knowledge" (with the problem still open), so I understood correctly.
So I mark the answer as accepted and have to wait until somebody solves the main problem, then my conjecture will also be solved :]

Comment: Given your choice of notation it seems likely that Dusart's 1998 paper inspired the question. It seems worth citing. http://www.unilim.fr/laco/theses/1998/T1998_01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi(n)$ be the number of primes not exceeding $n$, so $\pi(p_r)=r$ for all $r$. Then $\pi(p_k+p_l)\le\pi(p_k+p_l+1)\le1+\pi(p_k+p_l)$. If $p_k+p_l+1\le p_{k+l+1}$, then $\pi(p_k+p_l+1)\le k+l+1$, so $\pi(p_k+p_l)\le k+l+1=\pi(p_k)+\pi(p_l)+1$.

Now there is a conjecture that $\pi(x+y)\le\pi(x)+\pi(y)$ for all $x\ge2$, $y\ge2$, but this conjecture is generally believed to be false (although if there are counterexamples they involve very large numbers) (see [Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture). I suspect that a close inspection of the reasons for believing it false will also cast doubt on the veracity of $\pi(p_k+p_l)\le\pi(p_k)+\pi(p_l)+1$

Comment: It is believed to be false because it is incompatible with the [First Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture) $-$ see [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/21676/1508). [This page](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/apc.html) mentions an admissible prime constellation of length $11736$ and size $1412=\pi(11763)+3$, which (I think) suggests that $\pi(p_k+p_l) > \pi(p_k)+\pi(p_l)+3$ for infinitely many $k,l$.